# How to open a Sqlite3 database in read-only mode with persistent?

Tags: haskell, sqlite, readonly, yesod, persistent

I currently use `createSqlitePool` from persistent-sqlite:

```
import Database.Persist.Sqlite

createSqlitePool "mydb.db" 10
```

According to Sqlite3 documentation I can pass additional parameters in connection strings, e.g.

```
"Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Read Only=True;"
```

Cf. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite-net-provider/read-only-connection/

Apparently, it's not possible to simply pass this connection string to `createSqlitePool`. Is there a way to tell persistent-sqlite to open my database read-only?

Comment: sqlite, being a file based database, doesn't have the concept of 'connection strings'. It doesn't even have connections, because the dbms here is just a library in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persistent now supports Sqlite3-URI-syntax in connection strings, as documented here:

https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Database-Configuration

Thus, for read-only something like this works:

URI filename style, relative path, read-only:

```
file:sqlite3.db?mode=ro
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that's .NET specific information you're linking to, so it probably doesn't apply here.

If you look at [the code](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/persistent-sqlite/2.2/persistent-sqlite/Database/Sqlite.hs#L188), persistent just calls the SQLite C function [`sqlite3_open`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) which only takes the filename of the database.

It looks like it would need to use `sqlite3_open_v2` which take additional flags, if you wanted to make the connection read-only.

You can probably achieve the same thing using file permissions though, since a user won't be able to write the SQLite DB file if they don't have permission to do so.

Comment: It seems reasonable to open an issue on Persistent about this @ruben.moor. It might not be too difficult to implement yourself, either.

Comment: I'll try out the approach with simple read-only permission on the db file. It sounds sufficient for all practical purposes. One might argue though, that a read-only access specified in the haskell code is cleaner (depending on the circumstances) and I'll take a look into the necessary changes for that, as well.